Any special meaning for this weird ObjectName value in Kernelbase.dll in Windows 10/11 passed to NtOpenKey
This function in kernelbase.dll :
_ReadSettingsCache@8 proc near

DestinationString= _UNICODE_STRING ptr -0F0h
ObjectAttributes= _OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ptr -0E8h
KeyHandle= dword ptr -0D0h
Handle= dword ptr -0CCh
Source= dword ptr -0C8h
MaxCount= dword ptr -0C4h
KeyValueInformation= byte ptr -0C0h
var_4= dword ptr -4

mov     edi, edi
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 0F4h
mov     eax, ___security_cookie
xor     eax, ebp
mov     [ebp+var_4], eax
push    ebx
push    esi
push    edi
lea     eax, [ebp+ObjectAttributes]
mov     [ebp+ObjectAttributes.Length], 18h
push    eax             ; ObjectAttributes
xor     ebx, ebx
mov     [ebp+ObjectAttributes.RootDirectory], edx
xor     edi, edi
mov     [ebp+ObjectAttributes.Attributes], 40h ; '@'
inc     ebx
mov     [ebp+KeyHandle], edi
push    ebx             ; DesiredAccess
lea     eax, [ebp+KeyHandle]
mov     [ebp+Handle], edi
push    eax             ; KeyHandle
mov     esi, ecx
mov     [ebp+ObjectAttributes.ObjectName], offset _ExplicitSettingsKey
mov     [ebp+ObjectAttributes.SecurityDescriptor], edi
mov     [ebp+ObjectAttributes.SecurityQualityOfService], edi
call    ds:__imp__NtOpenKey@12 ; NtOpenKey(x,x,x)

This points to a UNICODE_STRING structure here:
.text:75DDFBF0 _ExplicitSettingsKey db  0Ch            ; DATA XREF: ReadSettingsCache(x,x)+54↓o
.text:75DDFBF1                 db    0
.text:75DDFBF2                 db  0Eh
.text:75DDFBF3                 db    0
.text:75DDFBF4                 db 0CCh ; OFF32 SEGDEF [_text,75E2CECC]
.text:75DDFBF5                 db 0CEh
.text:75DDFBF6                 db 0E2h
.text:75DDFBF7                 db  75h ; u

We look at the address for the buffer:
.text:75E2CECC _ExplicitSettingsKey_buffer db  3Ch ; <
.text:75E2CECD                 db 0D8h
.text:75E2CECE                 db  0Eh
.text:75E2CECF                 db 0DFh
.text:75E2CED0                 db  3Ch ; <
.text:75E2CED1                 db 0D8h
.text:75E2CED2                 db  0Fh
.text:75E2CED3                 db 0DFh
.text:75E2CED4                 db  3Ch ; <
.text:75E2CED5                 db 0D8h
.text:75E2CED6                 db  0Dh
.text:75E2CED7                 db 0DFh
.text:75E2CED8                 db    0
.text:75E2CED9                 db    0
.text:75E2CEDA                 db    0
.text:75E2CEDB                 db    0

Generally in my experience objectName parameter of ObjectAttributes has a string, passed to NtOpenKey it contains a key name, but this one is odd.
Any ideas on why this odd string is used or steps to work out further?
The same byte sequence is used in basesrv.dll in a function of the same name.

interesting. have you managed to catch that code in action and see if it actually manages to open the key? I tried it out with a custom program and got back STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND.

it tries but fails, it is so weird.

Looks like a developer was having fun:
.rdata:0000000180190858 ExplicitSettingsKey_buffer:             ; DATA XREF: .rdata:ExplicitSettingsKey↑o
.rdata:0000000180190858                 text "UTF-16LE", '',0
.rdata:0000000180190866                 db    0
.rdata:0000000180190867                 db    0

